# Multiple continues references in Microsoft office word 2013

Tags: academic-writing, software, tools, resources, microsoft-word

I'm writing a paper for IEEE using Microsoft office `Word 2013`. I want to use `dynamic reference` which is available in this version of `Word`. In a place of my article the `references` are similar to:

> bla bla `[1,2,3,4,5]`

How can I convert it to some thing like `[1]-[5]` without losing dynamic ability? 
In other words I do not want to convert my references to `static text`.

Comment: Does this help? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mark-index-entries-for-text-that-spans-a-range-of-pages-bbe9a6ee-a843-4533-b5fb-47f1f4b49c68 If not, try to search for something like "word pages range index".

Answer (score 1):

According to this [page on word.tips.net,](https://word.tips.net/T000211_Reference_to_a_Range_of_Endnotes.html) this is not possible in Word.

There is instead a suggestion to hide the middle references and add a dash:

> One solution is to select the intermediate references in the range, format them as hidden text, and then add a dash. For instance, you could select ",4,5," from the references "3,4,5,6", format the selection as hidden text, and then add a dash to provide the result of "3-6". If you have quite a few such operations to perform in your text, you can automate it slightly by using the following macro:
>
> `Sub RefListToRange()
>       Selection.Font.Hidden = True
>       Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
>       Selection.TypeText Text:="–"
>   End Sub`
>
> Select the portion you want to hide (such as ",4,5,") and the macro does the hiding and adds the dash.